# Tkinter button highlight feature stops working after command is called

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been working on my first GUI in tkinter - I am using Windows. My goal right now is to have buttons that accomplish these goals:

1. The buttons are highlighted when moused over.
2. The button remains highlighted if clicked.
3. Only one button can be "selected" (click-highlighted) at a time.

I initially thought that I had accomplished this! But I realize now that my work is not complete.

Here is what I am seeing:

1. I mouse over button A. It becomes highlighted! (GOOD)
2. I click on button A. It stays highlighted! (GOOD)
3. I mouse over button B. It becomes highlighted! (GOOD)
4. I click on button B. It stays highlighted! The highlight from A is removed! (GOOD)
5. I mouse over button A. It does not highlight. (BAD)

I am calling the default_coloring class function on button A when I click on button B. However, this appears to turn off the highlighting functions of button A, and the button no longer functions correctly according to the three rules I listed at the top.

How do I ensure that the buttons continue to function normally, even after the command is called? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

```
  import tkinter as tk

  blue = '#0000BB'
  white = '#FFFFFF'

  class HoverButton(tk.Button):
        def __init__(self, master, position = None, **kw):
              tk.Button.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
              self.defaultBackground = self["background"]
              self.defaultForeground = self["foreground"]
              self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
              self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
              self.bind("<Button-1>", self.hover_click)
              self.state = 0
              self.position = position

        def on_enter(self, e):
              if self.state == 0:
                    self['background'] = self['activebackground']
                    self['foreground'] = self['activeforeground']

        def on_leave(self, e):
              if self.state == 2:
                    self.state = 0
              if self.state == 0:
                    self['background'] = self.defaultBackground
                    self['foreground'] = self.defaultForeground

        def hover_click(self, e):
              self.state += 1
              self.state = self.state % 3
              if self.state == 2:
                    self['background'] = self.defaultBackground
                    self['foreground'] = self.defaultForeground

        def default_coloring(self):
              self['background'] = self.defaultBackground
              self['foreground'] = self.defaultForeground

  class AddOnFrame(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, master):
              self.selectedbutton = None
              super().__init__(master)
              games = ['A','B','C']
              self.objs = list()
              self['bg'] = blue
              for i in range(3):
                    self.objs.append(HoverButton(self,position = i, text = games[i].upper(), activebackground = white,activeforeground = blue,fg = white, bg = blue, borderwidth=0, relief = 'flat', highlightbackground = white))
                    self.objs[i]['command'] = lambda c=i: self._hover_button_clicked(self.objs[c])
                    self.objs[i].grid(row = i, column = 0, sticky = tk.W + tk.E)
              self.blanklabel = tk.Label(self, text = '', background = white)
              self.blanklabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1,rowspan = 10, sticky = tk.N + tk.E + tk.W + tk.S)
              self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=10)
              self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1, minsize=500)
              self.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1, minsize=500)
              self.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1, minsize=500)
              self.pack(expand = True)

        def _hover_button_clicked(self, HoverButton):
              self.lastbutton = self.selectedbutton
              if self.lastbutton != None:
                    self.objs[self.lastbutton].default_coloring()
              self.selectedbutton = HoverButton.position

  window = tk.Tk()
  window.geometry('1750x950')
  window['bg'] = blue
  window.title('Testing')
  lf = AddOnFrame(window)
  lf['bg'] = blue

  window.mainloop()
```

Comment: 5th step working for me, what platform are you working on (Windows, Linux, Mac; if linux which distro/desktop)?

Comment: @unlut I am on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the main source of the problem. When another button is clicked, you restore color of the last clicked button, but you do not reset its state. Change your default_coloring function to:

```
def default_coloring(self):
          self.state = 0
          self['background'] = self.defaultBackground
          self['foreground'] = self.defaultForeground
```

But you should also prevent default_coloring if same button is pressed again:

```
def _hover_button_clicked(self, HoverButton):
          self.lastbutton = self.selectedbutton
          if (self.lastbutton != None) and (self.lastbutton != HoverButton.position):
                self.objs[self.lastbutton].default_coloring()
          self.selectedbutton = HoverButton.position
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Stupid mistake on my part. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After cursory inspection, this sequence seems to be the problem:

- When a button is clicked, the `AddOnFrame._hover_button_clicked`
  method is invoked.
- `AddOnFrame.selectedbutton` is initially `None`, which means the
  if-statement in `AddOnFrame._hover_button_clicked` will not be
  executed the first time. This is why the buttons seem to work the
  first time you click them, but not after that.
- However, the next time it is invoked (the next time a button is
  pressed), `AddOnFrame.selectedbutton` is not `None`, and will never
  be `None` again, meaning that from now on, every click will result in
  a call to that `HoverButton`'s `default_coloring` method.
- `default_coloring` is invoked as soon as a button is clicked, which
  results in a quick flash from the active color to the default color,
  and the button does not stay highlighted.

The quick fix:

Basically, don't do the `default_coloring` stuff. It seems to be hurting you more than it's helping. Not really sure why you're doing it in the first place (all that stuff with setting the command, the lambda, the whole `_hover_button_clicked` method) since the buttons seem to be setting their colors back to the default just fine when `on_leave` or `hover_click` are invoked. You can fix your problem by changing the body of your `HoverButton.default_coloring` function to this:

```
def default_coloring(self):
    return
```

The real fix would be some restructuring of your code.

**EDIT** I'm offering this to help you simplify things:

```
import tkinter as tk

colors = {
    "white": "#FFFFFF",
    "blue": "#0000BB"
}


class HoverButton(tk.Button):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.is_selected = False
        self.is_highlighted = False
        self["borderwidth"] = 0
        self["relief"] = tk.FLAT
        self["font"] = ("United Sans Cd Bk", 30)
        self["activeforeground"] = colors["blue"]
        self["activebackground"] = colors["white"]
        self["highlightbackground"] = colors["white"]
        self.recolor()

        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_click)

    def recolor(self):
        self["background"] = [colors["blue"], colors["white"]][self.is_highlighted]
        self["foreground"] = [colors["white"], colors["blue"]][self.is_highlighted]

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.is_highlighted = True
        self.recolor()

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        if self.is_selected:
            return
        self.is_highlighted = False
        self.recolor()

    def on_click(self, *args):
        self.is_selected = not self.is_selected


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Window")
        self.geometry("256x256")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self["background"] = colors["blue"]

        button_labels = ["A", "B", "C"]
        self.buttons = []
        for row, button_label in enumerate(button_labels):
            button = HoverButton(text=button_label)
            button.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
            self.buttons.append(button)


def main():

    application = Application()
    application.mainloop()

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Thank you for your post! I will be taking your feedback and incorporating the code structure into my GUI. However, the code doesn't take 3rd rule into account - I only want one button to be selected at a time.